# Mapstruct not mapping attributes correctly/at all

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping, mapstruct

This is my SignUpRequestDTo class:

```
package ez.ndvz.application.api.v1.dto.authenticationDTOs;
@Data
@Builder
public class SignUpRequestDTO {

    @NonNull
    @NotBlank
    String name;

    @NotBlank
    @NonNull
    String lastName;

    @NonNull
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\+(389)\\s?([2-7]0|78|77|75|76|71|72|73|74)\\s?([0-9]{6})$", message = "Invalid phone number format for North Macedonia")
    String phoneNumber;

    @NotBlank
    @NonNull
    @Email
    String email;

    @NonNull
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 6)
    String password;
}
```

And this is my User class

```
package ez.ndvz.core.domain.models;
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String lastName;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    private Set<Roles> roles;

    private List<Property> propertyList;
}
```

And I am using MapStruct to map my dto to my domain class and this is what my mapper interaface looks like:

```
package ez.ndvz.application.api.v1.mapper;
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserHttpMapper {


    User toDomain(SignUpRequestDTO signUpRequestDTO);

    User toDomain(SignInRequestDTO signInRequestDTO);

    UserEntity toEntity(SignInRequestDTO signInRequestDTO);

    UserEntity toEntity(SignUpRequestDTO signUpRequestDTO);
}
```

But this isn't working properly as It's not mapping the attributes from my DTO class to my user class when I access the build generated file:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2024-02-14T11:32:45+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: IncrementalProcessingEnvironment from gradle-language-java-8.2.jar, environment: Java 19.0.2 (Amazon.com Inc.)"
)
@Component
public class UserHttpMapperImpl implements UserHttpMapper {

    @Override
    public User toDomain(SignUpRequestDTO signUpRequestDTO) {
        if ( signUpRequestDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        User.UserBuilder user = User.builder();

        return user.build();
    }

    @Override
    public User toDomain(SignInRequestDTO signInRequestDTO) {
        if ( signInRequestDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        User.UserBuilder user = User.builder();

        return user.build();
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity toEntity(SignInRequestDTO signInRequestDTO) {
        if ( signInRequestDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        UserEntity.UserEntityBuilder userEntity = UserEntity.builder();

        return userEntity.build();
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity toEntity(SignUpRequestDTO signUpRequestDTO) {
        if ( signUpRequestDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        UserEntity.UserEntityBuilder userEntity = UserEntity.builder();

        return userEntity.build();
    }
}
```

as you can see no attributes are being mapped.
Even when I add the following:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserHttpMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "name",source = "name")
    @Mapping(target = "lastName",source = "lastName")
    @Mapping(target = "phoneNumber",source = "phoneNumber")
    @Mapping(target = "email",source = "email")
    @Mapping(target = "password",source = "password")
    User toDomain(SignUpRequestDTO signUpRequestDTO);
```

I get this error:

```
error: No property named "name" exists in source parameter(s). Type "SignUpRequestDTO" has no properties.
    User toDomain(SignUpRequestDTO signUpRequestDTO)
```

I think the issue could potentially be with my DTO class?
These are the gradle depedendencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':domain')
    implementation project(':infrastructure:persistance')
    implementation project(':infrastructure:authentication')

    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'

    implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'


    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Comment: Most likely an issue with lombok and mapstruct together. You might need to add `lombok-mapstruct-binding` annotationProcessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `lombok-mapstruct-binding` processor:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0'
}
```